# Lync (formerly Office Communicator) with pidgin-sipe => Read Error

Tags: pidgin, sip, office-communicator, pidgin-sipe, microsoft-lync

I always could connect to my companys Microsoft Lync network which is based on SIP. There is an addon for Pidgin called `pidgin-sipe`. Everything worked fine unless the company changed something weird.
Now I always get a `Read Error` when I want to connect.

The debug output shows the following:
http://fixee.org/paste/vmfb4sl/

Isn't it possible anymore to connect or is this an error of `pidgin-sipe`?

Comment: You might want to give [wync](http://fisil.com/linuxlync.html) a try instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add:

```
NSS_SSL_CBC_RANDOM_IV=0
```

to /etc/environment

and it will persist without you needing a non-standard startup script for pidgin.

Comment: Doesn't it have any impact on other applications?

Comment: Yes. It does in that location. [This is the right method.](http://askubuntu.com/a/606980/29097)

Answer (score 16):

~$ export NSS_SSL_CBC_RANDOM_IV=0

~$ pidgin

Seems to do the trick, not sure exactly what it does. I need to read up on it.

Here is the bug traq for the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pidgin/+bug/950790

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I just created a custom script to start pidgin with this setting. Would be nice to hear from you if you know what this option does exactly.

Comment: Thanks! it seems to solve the "Read error", but I still getting auth error. Did you have to configure something special?

Comment: Note: You can avoid having to use a script by condensing this into one command: `NSS_SSL_CBC_RANDOM_IV=0 pidgin`

Comment: Perfect! Works for Windows as well! (Add that into user environment)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is the old way.. [Find the new way here](http://askubuntu.com/a/606980/29097)

Answer (score 8):

## Other answers are old ways.

There is now a config file you should edit.

```
sudo -e /etc/default/pidgin-sipe
```

Uncomment the line that reads,

```
# export NSS_SSL_CBC_RANDOM_IV=0
```

(remove the '#' write the file and restart pidgin)

Answer (score 1):

To get it working with how you normally start applications in Ubuntu, and not getting into the way of other programs, you can copy the `pidgin`'s launcher to `~/.local/share/applications/` directory by issuing the following commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
cp /usr/share/applications/pidgin.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then edit the file with your favorite editor, e.g.

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/pidgin.desktop
```

Replace the line `Exec=/usr/bin/pidgin` with the following:

```
Exec=env NSS_SSL_CBC_RANDOM_IV=0 /usr/bin/pidgin
```

Comment: While this method works. It's way complex and doesn't catch invocations of pidgin from other routes. [Try this instead](http://askubuntu.com/a/606980/29097)